# Give gcloud virtual machine a custom domain

Tags: virtual-machine, google-compute-engine, gcloud

Hi I am currently using a gcloud virtual machine as a ftp server. I would like to give the virtual machine one of my custom domains, (I use godaddy). My current VM address is something like this 64.128.64.64 (not real one) I would like to change it to example.com (my custom go daddy domain). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ensure you're using a static IP address on the VM, see:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses#externaladdresses

Use GoDaddy's DNS manager to add an "A" record to your domain, mapping some host name (e.g. `your-ftp.example.com`) to the static IP address of the VM.

Answer (score 0):

According to Google Cloud Platform’s [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/tutorials/create-domain-tutorial/) and godaddy’s  [documentation](https://in.godaddy.com/help/change-nameservers-for-my-domains-664), follow below steps to configure your domain to your server -

1. Navigate to create a DNS zone page on google cloud console (or click this shortcut).
2. Enter the details as -
   (i) Zone name - [any name]
   (ii) Zone type - public
   (iii) DNS name - your godaddy DNS suffix name (eg - example.com)
   (iv) DNSSEC - off
3. Click create. It will set up a zone with NS SOA records, now you have to add an A record by following steps -
   (i) On the Zone details page, click Add record set.
   (ii) Select A from the Resource Record Type menu.
   (iii) For IPv4 Address, enter the external IP address (Make sure it is a static external IP address, not ephemeral) for your instance.
   (iv) Click Create to create the A record for your zone.
4. Add a CNAME record to account for a prefix to your domain name (for example, www.):
   (i) Click Add Record Set.
   (ii) In the DNS Name field, add the prefix (eg - www) for the domain.
   (iii) For Resource Record Type, choose CNAME.
   (iv) For Canonical name, enter the domain name, followed by a period (for example, example.com.).
   (v) Click Create.
5. On the Zone details page, make a note of the NS records. You will need these records to proceed with Step 6(iv).
6. Navigate to the Domain Control Centre in godaddy.com after logging in.
   (i) Select your domain to access the Domain Settings page.
   (ii) Under Additional Settings, select Manage DNS.
   (iii) In the Nameservers section, select Change.
   (iv) Choose the option -     Enter my own nameservers (advanced) then enter the nameserver you saved in step 5.
   (v) Select Save or Connect.
   (vi) Check the box next to Yes, I consent to update Nameservers for the selected domain(s).